# Convert data from PDFform to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pdf, pdf-form

I am trying to convert the data entered in multiple fill-able pdf-forms to one csv file.
This code consists of a few steps:

1. Open new .csv file (header row)
2. Open multiple pdf-forms with "for...in" loop
3. Convert data entered in form-fields to csv

However, when running the command I receive the error:

```
fc-int01-generateAppearances: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\Scripts\test3.py", line 31, in <module>
        writer.writerow(value)
    _csv.Error: sequence expected
```

If I just the print value (form data) in python, it works. But importing the data does not. There is maybe also a problem of going from row to column with value. I hope I am clear.

Here is my code:

```
import glob
import os
import sys
import csv
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

#input file path for specific file
#filename = "C:\Python27\Scripts\MH_1.pdf"
#fp = open(filename, 'rb')

#open new csv file
out_file=open('C:\Users\Wonen\Downloads\Test\output.csv', 'w+')
writer = csv.writer(out_file)
#header row
writer.writerow(('Name coordinator', 'Date', 'Address', 'District',
                 'City', 'Complaintnr'))

#enter folder path to open multiple files
path = 'C:\Users\Wonen\Downloads\Test'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pdf')):
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
    #read pdf's
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    #doc.initialize()    # <<if password is required
    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']
    for i in fields:
        field = resolve1(i)
        name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')
        print '{0}: {1}'.format(name, value)
        writer.writerow(value)
```

---

The output with a text pdf (including all output) using `print (repr(value))`:

```
None
'Crip Gang'
None
None
None
/Ja
None
/1
/1
None
None
/Ja
/Ja
None
None
None
'wfwf'
'sd'
'dfwf'
'ffasf'
'tsdbd'
'dfadfasdf'
None
'df'
None
'asdff'
None
'wff'
None
'ffs'
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
'1'
'2'
'7'
/0
'Ja'
'Two unlimited'
'Captain Jack'
None
'www.kijkbijmij.nl'
'Onderverhuur'
/Ja
```

etc. etc. "None" stands for "empty text box"; and "1" and "0" stand for "yes" and "no" outputs.

Comment: What's the output of the `print` function one line before the error happens?

Comment: `value` needs to be a sequence. If it's not already, try `writer.writerow([value])`.

Comment: @martineau, the problem is almost solved. I would like it to be comma-seperated values on a row (cleaning white space in between). But this goes way beyond my knowledge of python.

Comment: `writerow()` will put a comma between each element in the sequence passed to it as an argument. When you use `[value]`, the sequence is comprised of only one element, everything in `value`. Please show us what the data is in `value` looks like. If it's different for each field, then we need to know that, too.

Comment: @martineau I edited this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last part of your code as shown:

```
    .
    .
    .
#enter folder path to open multiple files
path = 'C:\Users\Wonen\Downloads\Test'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pdf')):
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
    #read pdf's
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    #doc.initialize()    # <<if password is required
    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']
    row = []
    for i in fields:
        field = resolve1(i)
        name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')
        row.append(value)
    writer.writerow(row)

out_file.close()
```

It's not clear this will work, but it may provide you with the information you need to solve your problem.

One confusing thing is that for the first header row of the csv:

```
writer.writerow(('Name coordinator', 'Date', 'Address','District','City', 'Complaintnr'))
```

which defines how many field values will be contained in each row written. This means that `fields` should be a list consisting of data for those 6 items in that order.

You need to figure out how to translate what's in each group of `fields` into a `row` list of 6 data items. That is what the code in my answer does — I think, but can't test.

Comment: This looks a lot better! I have two problems left. 1.Some value-fields allow 'enter' and make the output jump rows in csv. 2. The script scrapes the form backwards.

Comment: `writer.writerow(('Name coordinator', 'Date', 'Address','District','City', 'Complaintnr'))` writes my header row in the csv. I gave you a sample header code. The form has 25 questions, hence woud contain 25 headers instead of 6. This line is far longer than shown here.

Comment: You may have to check the values before appending them to the row list. That way you can change what gets added for special cases like when there's 'enter' or `None`. If by "scrapes backwards" you mean the field values are in the opposite order, you may be able to fix that with `writer.writerow(list(reversed(row)))`.

Comment: `writer.writerow(list(reversed(row)))` was exactly what I needed, thanks again. "check the values before appending them to the row list" I do not know how. Good tip though. I will search for that on the web, unless you have a solution ready :-)

Comment: You can check and correct the values before the `row.append()` with a series of `if` statements: i.e. `if value is None: value = ''`, `elif value == '1': value = 'yes'`, etc. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting and/or up-voting it. Thanks.

Comment: `if value == None:
           print 'ok'
 elif '\n' in value:    
           value.replace('\n',' ')`

I am trying to remove linebreaks, but I get error `TypeError: argument of type 'PSLiteral' is not iterable` >>> for line value.replace('\n',' ')

Comment: Doesn't seem like `value` should ever be of type `PSLiteral`. It's also unclear whether the error is from the `if '\n' in value` or the `value.replace('\n',' ')`. Anyway, a workaround might be to add a `value = str(value) if value is not None else value` right after the `name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')` line. It could also be a bug in PDFMiner (that you should report).

Comment: P.S. You could also wrap the offending line(s) in a `try:` + `<line(s)>` + `except ValueError: pass` exception handler and attempt to just ignore it.