# TypeError: argument of type 'PSLiteral' is not iterable

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning, pdftotext

I am trying to remove some hidden enters using my pdfform-scraper-script before I write it into a csv file. But I keep receiving the error mentioned in the title. The relevant piece of code is:

```
import glob
import os
import sys
import csv
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

path = 'C:\Users\Wonen\Downloads\Test'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pdf')):
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
    #read pdf's
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    #doc.initialize()    # <<if password is required
    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']
    row = []
    for i in fields:
        field = resolve1(i)
        name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')
        #removing 'hidden enter'
        if value == None:
           print 'ok'
        elif value == NotImplementedError:
            print 'ok'
        elif '\n' in value:    
           value.replace('\n',' ')
        elif '\r' in value:    
           value.replace('\r',' ')
        row.append(value)
    writer.writerow(list(reversed(row)))
```

The complete error (+output) is:

ok

ok

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\Scripts\test3.py", line 37, in 
>       elif '\n' in value:     TypeError: argument of type 'PSLiteral' is not iterable

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you check the type of `value` and can you print its content?

Comment: @alec_djinn Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521403/convert-data-from-pdfform-to-csv

Comment: Try `elif '\n' in str(value):` ... does it solve?

Comment: Thanks. Now the script works but it does not remove the new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the content of the input file it's hard to guess. I think that the problem is that you get some non string value when calling `field.get('V')` to solve this I suggest you to change `value` to a string.
Try like this:

```
if value == None:
   print 'ok'
elif value == NotImplementedError:
    print 'ok'
elif '\n' in str(value):
   value = str(value)    
   value.replace('\n',' ')
elif '\r' in str(value):
   value = str(value)    
   value.replace('\r',' ')
```

Comment: How do I change `value` to string?  Can I do it after running `field.get('V')`?

Comment: A normal print output is clean. That is why I am confused :-s.